# How to Join three tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables : Orders, Customers and Suppliers

Structure and Data:

#### Orders

```
================================
OrdNo, OrdDt,     OrdType, CSID
--------------------------------
1      01/04/2011    C     2
2      01/04/2011    S     1
--------------------------------
```

#### Customers

```
----------
CID, CName
----------
1    John
2    Boby
----------
```

#### Suppliers

```
=========
SID, SName
----------
1    Tony
2    Mohan
----------
```

If OrdTYpe = "C" then pick data from Customers table for CSID = CID
If OrdTYpe = "S" then pick data from Suppliers table for CSID = SID

How to list the records like

```
--------------------------------------
OrdNo, OrdDt,     OrdType, CSID  CSName
--------------------------------------
1      01/04/2011    C     2     Boby
2      01/04/2011    S     1     Tony
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your structure seems wrong. Having 2 different types of `id` in the `csid` column means that you won't be able to enforce referential integrity and are left having to do messy joins like the one you need in the question.

Comment: You do realize that this structure will require a trigger to protect against orphaned rows because you will not be able to use a foreign key constraint. Thus, what stops someone from adding CSID = 12345, OrdType = 'C'? What stops someone from deleting the Customer row where CID = 2 and orphaning their orders?

Comment: Under no circumstances would I allow this design to stay this way, you are asking for data integrity issues. Never allow a column to have multiple meanings depending on another column especially when it should be a foreign key.

Comment: Seems like it's not just one column that's assigned multiple meanings. As far as I can see, orders by customers and those from suppliers are supposed to be stored in one table here. And that is rather wrong, in my opinion, as they are very distinct entities (even if similar ones).

Answer (score 4):

Does this get what you want?

```
SELECT ordno, orddt, ordtype, csid,
       COALESCE( c.name, s.name ) csname
  FROM orders o
    LEFT JOIN customer c ON o.ordtype='C' AND c.cid = o.csid
    LEFT JOIN suppliers s ON o.ordtype='S' AND c.sid = o.csid
```

Another possibility, at least in Oracle, would be:

```
SELECT ordno, orddt, ordtype, csid,
       CASE WHEN ordtype='C' THEN (SELECT name FROM customer WHERE cid = csid)
            WHEN ordtype='S' THEN (SELECT name FROM suppliers WHERE sid = csid)
       END csname
  FROM orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin has a good point. I'm no pro, but I would suggest making an intermediate table that will allow you to keep customers and suppliers separate, yet still pull from a common set of id's

Orders

```
========================
OrdNo, OrdDt,     CSID
------------------------
1      01/04/2011   2
2      01/04/2011   1
-------------------------
```

ClientIDs

```
---
ID
---
1
2
3
4
---
```

Customers

```
----------
CID, CName
----------
1    John
3    Boby
----------
```

Suppliers

```
=========
SID, SName
----------
2    Tony
4    Mohan
----------
```

That way you end up with something like this:

```
-------------------------------
OrdNo, OrdDt,      CSID  CSName
-------------------------------
1      01/04/2011    2     Tony
2      01/04/2011    1     John
-------------------------------
```

and by back tracking up through the (now) unique ID you will be able to tell if it is a customer, or supplier... also I'm pretty sure your SQL will run faster with this route (don't hold me to it though). If you like this idea, I could look into SQL to back it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.[OrdNo], o.[OrdDt], o.[OrdType], o.[CSID],
    CASE WHEN o.[OrdType] = 'C'
        THEN c.[CName]
        ELSE s.[SName]
    END as [CSName]
FROM Orders AS o
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c
    ON o.[CSID] = c.[CID]
LEFT JOIN Suppliers AS s
    ON o.[CSID] = s.[SID]
```