# How To create a jointure between more than 2 tables SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Join three tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781078/how-to-join-three-tables)

I have 4 tables :

- folder (id_folder,name)
- subfolder(id_subfolder,id_folder,name,othercolumn,...)
- piece(id_piece,id_subfolder,id_folder)
- image(id_image,id_piece,name,..)

How can I get all the contents of one folder ("id_folder=1" for example)?

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve, all images for all pieces for all subfolders in folder 1?

Comment: Close - "how to make teh join" is a frequently asked question.

Comment: And a bazillion others questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would `JOIN` your tables, something like this:

```
select *
from folder f
left join subfolder sf
    on f.id_folder = sf.id_folder
left join piece p
    on sf.id_subfolder = p.id_subfolder
    and sf.id_folder = p.id_folder
left join image i
    on p.id_piece = i.id_piece
where f.id_folder = 1
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, then there is a great [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that will help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a zero to many relationship between these tables something like this could work:

```
SELECT folder.id_folder, folder.name, subfolder.id_subfolder, subfolder.name, subfolder.othercolumn, piece.id_piece, image.id_image, image.name
FROM folder
LEFT JOIN subfolder
ON folder.id_Folder = subfolder.id_folder
LEFT JOIN Piece
ON subfolder.id_subfolder = piece.id_subfolder
LEFT JOIN [image]
on piece.id_piece = image.id_piece
WHERE folder.id_folder = 1;
```